# css() doesn't get fired with first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle the css of two buttons in a list. If one is clicked, the other one should have no border, and vice versa. Here's my code:

```
function navigate_menu(event, ec){

    $(event).css("border-top", "3px solid rgba(102,205,0, 0.8)");
   var search_id=$(event).attr("name");
   var chartid = "pie_chart_"+$(event).attr("name");
   var editid = "edit_"+$(event).attr("name");

   if(ec=="c"){

        $(".li-edit").css("border-top", "0px solid rgba(102,205,0, 0.8)");      
        $("#"+chartid).appendTo($("#chart_"+search_id+"_container"));
        $("#"+editid).css("display","none");
        $("#"+chartid).css("display","block");


   }else{

        $(".li-chart").css("border-top", "0px solid rgba(102,205,0, 0.8)");         
        $("#"+editid).appendTo($("#chart_"+search_id+"_container"));
        $("#"+chartid).css("display","none");
        $("#"+editid).css("display","block");


   }  
 }
```

HTML:

```
+"<ul id=\"navigation_list\">"
        +"<li onclick=\"navigate_menu(this,'c')\" class=\"li-chart\" name=\""+search_id+"\">Chart &amp; Legend</li>"
        +"<li onclick=\"navigate_menu(this,'e')\" class=\"li-edit\" name=\""+search_id+"\">Edit Chart\\Change Data</li>"
+"</ul>"
```

So, when I first click, nothing happens, and then after the second it works. Then when I click on the other button, same (first nothing, second works). I thought that maybe on the first click it thinks I click on the parent (`ul`), but I don't know how would I fix it. And sorry for the pluses, its because this "menu" gets added to multiple elements from a JS function.

I have also tried `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, still same outcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use jQuery to handle your events instead of making them inline?

Comment: @Adjit , because the document loads slow. It loads about 40 charts from an external source etc etc. On "ready" happens a little late

Comment: You don't need to delegate your events in `ready()` Try using `$(document).on('click', '.li-chart', function(){ });`

Comment: I don't really know why honestly. I feel more comfortable with this way. Is there a difference between what I do and "$(document).on(cl.." ? I'm trying to learn

Comment: The difference being `ready()` is fired when the document loads. `.on()` event is delegated as soon as the JS is read in, and is necessary to work with dynamic elements

Answer (score 1):

Give each a `li` a shared class, e.g. `li-item`:

```
<ul id="navigation_list">
    <li onclick="navigate_menu(this,'c')" class="li-chart li-item" name="+search_id+">Chart &amp; Legend</li>
    <li onclick="navigate_menu(this,'e')" class="li-edit li-item" name="+search_id">Edit Chart Change Data</li>
</ul>
```

Then use a JQuery `.on("click"` function to detect the click and apply the border to the clicked and remove from all others:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".li-item", function() {
        $(this).addClass("border");
        $(".li-item").not($(this)).removeClass("border");
    })
})
```

Make a CSS class with the style to apply:

```
.border {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w9bwq57m/

Comment: Anytime you use `$(document).on()` you should not need to wrap it in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: And if the user clicks before the DOM is ready with a really slow connection?

Comment: So long as the JS has been loaded there should be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Create `bordered` class in your css. Then call this `fn` somewhere in your click handler by passing `element` and second argument (no idea how to name it) I just wrote `context`. Make sure that you have deleted obsolete staff from the code above , which is responsible for border change .

```
function toggleBorder(element, context){

   if(context === 'c'){
      if($(".li-chart").hasClass('bordered')){
         $(".li-chart").removeClass('bordered');
      }
      $(".li-edit").addClass('bordered');

   }else{
      if($(".li-edit").hasClass('bordered')){
         $(".li-edit").removeClass('bordered');
      }
      $(".li-chart").addClass('bordered');
   }

}
```

Comment: But it does not matter to me if it has the class or not, because I remove the border anyway. Do you think that causes the problem?

Comment: why perform an operation if it is not necessary ? We should check if there is a class then perform the remove operation. But it is not what causes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jquery click instead of onlick on li elements. Also you'd need to add data-key="c" and data-key="e" to the li elements so those values can be passed to the function:

```
 $("#navigation_list li").click(function () {
    navigate_menu(this, $(this).data('key')); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sonya . I will try this as well. Is there any difference/reason?

Comment: I believe li doesn't have onclick event handler. You can attach it by using addEventListener or the jquery code above.